# Creating a slider bar using jQuery 1.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hai,

I've got a project which uses jQuery 1.2.1, and I cannot update the version. I need to create an incremental slider bar the same as the jQuery UI example (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps). The legacy download of jQuery UI is for 1.2.6 so even that will not cut the mustard.

Does anyone know of a way to emulate the same functionality using the older version of jQuery, or even know where I can download a version of jQuery UI which is compatible with jQuery 1.2.1 ?

Alternativly, does anyone know of any issues, such as deprecated functions, that might cause issues if I update the jQuery from 1.2.1 to 1.7.2 as this would be my ideal preference for all the obvious reasons.

Any help would be apprecaited.
Ta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem. Just use two jQuery versions at the same time

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/base/jquery-ui.1.7.2.css" type="text/css" /> 
//include 1.3.2 + UI
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
//call noConflict. Now you can reference the new jQuery via $j instead of $
<script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
//include 1.2.1 which is normally available via $ and jQuery
<script src="jquery-1.2.1.js"></script>
...
```

Demopage: http://jsbin.com/ofuma

Comment: I wish I could give you more votes, thank you so much for the great demo page!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try including the google-hosted jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and just comment out your current version. Then you can see whether everything stays compatible. I would have thought that would be a lot easier than trying to work with a legacy version.